# How much time does it take to transfer app to another play market account?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an application and I want to transfer it to another google play account, but I can't find information about app transferring time.

Comment: check this link https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213?hl=en

Comment: @JigneshJain do you find information on that link? I'm not.

Comment: yupp when i  give you link same time m searching but can't find that

Comment: i dont'need that link thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming, should be asked the support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s an outrageously simple process that took 2 hours to complete

check this link

[The steps to transferring your app/game](http://phandroid.com/2012/06/21/getting-acquired-how-to-transfer-ownership-of-your-android-app-or-game/)